# Mulesoft JIRA connector Projects - Get all

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb, mule4

Unable to fire this query against the Jira Cloud using Mulesoft Jira connector. Error received is.

```
jiraFlow.CPU_LITE @7d809c06] [event: 0-356c64c0-85d0-11eb-b94a-3800251e5a83] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: Initialising exception listener: org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler@63d07a91
```

- Anytime Studio version: 7.8.0
- Mule rutime version: 4.1.1 EE

[image]

Comment: Hi, you should provide also details of the name and version of the connector mentioned, and the flow in XML text and the connector configuration. In text please. Screenshots, as per the Stackoverflow guidelines, should only be used to show error messages that can not be copied and pasted as text. The complete error from the log should be added, in case any more lines are displayed that can provide more insights.

Answer (score 0):

The error details provided don't allow much insight, however using Mule 4.1.1 is completely not recommended. It is the first Mule 4 release from about 3 years ago, and doesn't include any of the many bug fixes and improvements from later releases. Try with Mule 4.3.0 that is the recommended last version.